# How do you reference monetdb odbc driver for .net

Tags: .net, visual-studio, monetdb, add-references-dialog

I'm trying to access a monetdb from a .net application - to see if it's feasible for me to use.  I have the ODBC Driver downloaded and installed on my machine (from monetDB.org).  I can't add a reference to it.  My assumption is that the correct file to reference is libMonetODBC.dll and that doesn't work - none of the others work either.  If I try to add a reference to it I get a message - "A reference to 'C:\Program Files\MonetDB\MonetDB ODBC Driver\lib\libMonetODBC.dll' could not be added.  Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

Has anyone tried this and how did you go about it?  Again, my assumption is that I should be able to reference the dll, like all others, and then add a using/imports statement to use it in the app.  I haven't seen a lot of documentation or other people using it from .net.  MonetDB.org doesn't seem to have steps for it either other than to use it from excel or something.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Add MonetDb driver to User Data Sources in ODBC Data Source Administrator

2) Add this reference in your project

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
```

3) Create a OdbcConnection using driver name
`var monetDbC = new OdbcConnection(@"Driver={MonetDB ODBC Driver};HOST=YourServerName;PORT=50000; Database=YourDBName;UID=monetdb; PWD=monetdb;");`

4) Query to MonetDB

```
 var odbcCmd = new OdbcCommand() { Connection = monetDbC };
 monetDbC.Open();
 odbcCmd.CommandText = query;
 odbcCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```